# how i can reload js file after change component in Angular 4

Tags: angular, routes, components

How can I reload a js file every time I change route component?

Because now the js file loads only when I load a page for the first time. When I change a route component, js doesn't work. If I reload a page then it works.

How can I fix this?

Now I require all js files in **angular-cli.json**

Comment: Can you describe purpose of your question? Why you need to reload JS every time? When you build angular - all your JS files (described in angular-cli.json, or loaded by `require`) combines in several JS files and loads one time. And you have all your code available.

Comment: I need it cause my sidebar doesn't work when i change route to another component, for example when I load home page sidebar works  if I use hover effect but if I change route component then sidebar doesn't work if I use hover.However, If i refresh the page then sidebar works as it should

Comment: I think it's problem of sidebar implementation. Is it uses JS to hover? maybe you can use CSS for it? It's very bad flow for reloading JS files.

Comment: just this js file of AdminLTE theme, I didn't think that It could be so diffucult(

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to enable hashing of webpack to be turned to true that way you will always be sure that you have a latest version of the JS in your browser. But if your browser do not load after rebuild of your angular application try restarting the browser and your system.

If you wish to enable the hashing in the webpack for your html file you need to make sure that you do the enable hashing to true please find the snippet of that code below,

```
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      // this value must be set based on your choice.
      "hash": false/true
});
```

that is for HtmlWebpackPlugin, have a look at the plugin github page that can provide you a little inside of "cache busting" in angular 2/4 applications.

#### [Webpack Html Plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin)